# RewriteRule to allow forward slash in query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following re-write rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ modules.php?mod_name=$1
```

It allows me to open a url like:

```
mydomain.com/settings
```

This calls the php file in the following format:

```
modules.php?mod_name=settings
```

However, I need to call my php script with mod_name values that contain a path e.g:

```
modules.php?mod_name=settings/preferences.php?id=1103
```

I would like the re-write rule to be able to accept the above in the following format:

```
mydomain.com/settings/preferences/1103
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php try this url

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ modules.php?mod_name=$1`

Your `\w` matches word characters ([a-z] [A-Z] [0-9]) and dashes (-) (thus not the /).

To include the /, you need something like `^([\w-/]+)$`

Comment: Thanks, i tried ^([\w-/])$ but that did not work, but then tried ^([\w-/]+)$  and that seems to work.

Comment: Doh!  I edited and you're exactly right.  The [...] just matches *one* of the chars, you need the + to match *one or more*